# How to get correct SUM() when joining table with duplicated row data?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, conditional-statements, aggregate-functions

Currently I have 3 tables, the first table 'Users' contains `id` and `user_name`. The second table 'listings' contains `refno` and `agent_id`. And my third table 'logs' contains `refno` and `status`. Now I want to display the name of a person next to their status. So basically I want the count of status entries from logs and put their respective username next to it.

To do this, I have to reference `refno` of 'logs' to `refno` of 'listings' and the `agent_id` of 'listings' to `id` of 'Users'. For this I have used the following statement:

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Draft' THEN 1 END) AS draft,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Publish' THEN 1 END) AS publish, 
       u.name
from logs t 
inner join listings l on t.refno = l.refno 
inner join users u on l.agent_id=u.id
```

But this returns an output like:

[image]

Which is wrong, the output I want is like this:

| Draft | Publish | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Jason |
| 0 | 1 | Jam |

I've added a sqlfiddle with data to make the reference easier to understand: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22b6e4/5

Comment: You can group results with: `group by l.agent_id`

Comment: Okay I tried this which is bringing the second row, but the first row data is incorrect if you check it in the fiddle

Comment: You have duplicate listing with a value of  "A123" on your listings table.

Comment: Yes, because "A123" isn't a unique value. The status of that listing was changed from publish to draft in a particular timeframe.

Comment: @JayVijayModi check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
Based upon your comments below, you need to first create pseudo table inside the `FROM` clause that must contain all the necessary data in order to get your desired results.
The below subquery creates a pseudo table that contains all the required data.

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.name,
       t.status,
       t.refno
FROM logs t 
INNER JOIN listings l ON t.refno = l.refno 
INNER JOIN users u ON l.agent_id = u.id
GROUP BY t.refno, u.name, t.status;
```

You simply need to wrap the above query as a subquery inside the `FROM` clause of your original query.
So here is the final query that gets your desired output.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tab.status = 'Draft' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS draft,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tab.status = 'Publish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS publish,
       tab.name
FROM (SELECT u.id,
      u.name,
      t.status,
      t.refno
      FROM logs t 
      INNER JOIN listings l ON t.refno = l.refno 
      INNER JOIN users u ON l.agent_id = u.id
      GROUP BY t.refno, u.name, t.status) AS tab
GROUP BY tab.name
ORDER BY tab.id;
```

**Original Answer:**

You need to add a `GROUP BY` clause to group the result according to your desired parameter(s).
Here you can either group by `l.agent_id` or `u.id`.

Another thing that i noticed is that you need to add an `ELSE` clause to your `SUM` statement to return `0` in case an unexpected `status` is returned from the query.
Something like this:
`SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Publish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

So your final query becomes something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Draft' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS draft,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Publish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS publish, 
       u.name 
FROM logs t 
INNER JOIN listings l ON t.refno = l.refno 
INNER JOIN users u ON l.agent_id=u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Comment: Hey so I tried this in my fiddle and still doesn't give me my desired output. Note: "A123" isn't a unique value. The status of that listing was changed from publish to draft in a particular timeframe.

Comment: @JayVijayModi if we're talking about timeframe, then i guess there is a need to add a timestamp to your schema

Comment: Yes in my original database there is a column with a timestamp, but right now for simplicity sake I've made the fiddle to output everything which basically means the full timeframe. And with this the output should be Jason->1->1 and Jam->0->1

Answer (score 1):

The glaring problem to overcome is the fact that you have non-unique data in your listings table -- this is skewing your sums.

You need to join only on unique rows so that you don't count a subsequently joined row more than once.

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.name,
       SUM(status = 'Draft') AS draft,
       SUM(status = 'Publish') AS publish
FROM users AS u
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM listings) AS l ON u.id = l.agent_id
JOIN logs AS t ON l.refno = t.refno
GROUP BY u.id
```

I prefer to include the id in the result set because names are often not unique.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22b6e4/48

Comment: Do you find the other answer to be superior to mine? @Jay

Comment: that's a more cleaner approach to solve the given problem!

Comment: Now that this sockpuppet has been deleted by mods, I guess there is no hope in shifting the accepted answer.  :(